# Loop Regression and Store Intercepts, Slopes, etc

Tags: r, loops, regression, linear-regression, linear-algebra

I need to use a loop to regress each company’s returns onto the index return:
The company return is:

```
       AAPL         AXP          BA         CAT        CSCO         CVX          DD         DIS          GE          GS          HD 
 12.3360728 -13.9214932  22.5635983 -27.2829432  24.1013814 -20.3403951   0.4449273  28.1967333  20.3767961   3.9267703  30.2680724 
        IBM        INTC         JNJ         JPM          KO         MCD         MMM         MRK        MSFT         NKE         PFE 
 -7.8815087   8.0829670  -1.3179946  12.5467514   8.2271155  24.7729246   7.6478088  -0.5601629  21.9812572  39.4680023  19.9745312 
         PG         TRV         UNH         UTX           V          VZ         WMT         XOM 
 -6.7330018  16.4542731  27.3932024  -1.2581727  41.5225073  -1.2022588 -23.1585254  -9.7806252
```

and the index return is:

```
    ^DJI 
4.910218
```

I want to:

1. print a table of intercepts, slopes (βi), and idiosyncratic standard deviations σRi (standard deviation of the residuals) for all companies i = 1, ..., 30,
2. compute and print the variance of the index’s return,
3. compute the single-index approximation to the covariance matrix, Qsi, using the computed σ^2M , βi and σRi for all i
   **Note: the diagonal entries of Ω are σ^2Ri, not σRi**

Basically I just need to do a loop of different regressions and somehow store that information. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example you can use to develop your own code. This code loops over variables of the `mtcars` dataset and estimates linear models using `mpg` as a target variable:

```
ref_variable <- "mpg"
target_vars <- c("hp","wt","qsec")

# container results
res <- data.frame(matrix(NA,0,4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(res) <- c("variable", "intercept", "slope", "std_dev_resid")

for (var in target_vars){
  linear_model <- lm(as.formula(paste0(ref_variable,"~",var)), data = mtcars)
  res <- rbind(res, data.frame(variable=var,
                      intercept=linear_model$coefficients[[1]], # intercept
                      slope=linear_model$coefficients[[2]], # slope
                      std_dev_resid=sd(resid(linear_model)) # std dev of residuals
                      ))
}
```

**Output**

```
  variable intercept       slope std_dev_resid
1       hp 30.098861 -0.06822828     0.5262956
2       wt 37.285126 -5.34447157     0.6674783
3     qsec -5.114038  1.41212484     0.3654127
```

Comment: thank you so much for this but I have to ask if this will also work for regressions between time series objects? I stupidly put one number to regress against another number but what I meant to do was regress one time series against another time series.

Comment: @eruiz of course, in my example I use a data frame. Its columns can be thought of as time series. Type 'mtcars' in Rstudio to inspect the data set.

Comment: @eruiz fixed one typo. Try the edited code, it works now

Comment: It worked wonderfully! I have a question about standard deviation of residuals though. In my assignment it says "idiosyncratic standard deviations σRi (standard deviation of the residuals)". What I understand is that `lm()` calculates sigma as `the square root of the estimated variance of the random error
σ^2 = 1/(n-p) Sum(w[i] R[i]^2),
where R[i] is the i-th residual, residuals[I].` Can you explain why you used the formula that you did?

Comment: @eruiz I actually don't know why I put 2 in there. Another typo I guess. My bad, sorry. You need std.dev of residuals? Then simply use `sd(resid(linear_model))`

Comment: @eruiz Do you have any other questions?

Comment: This was very helpful, I was able to create my table for my various regressions. Would you happen to know how to do part 3 in my original question. I need to compute a single-index approximation to a covariance matrix Qsi using the computed σM2 ,βi (slopes) and σRi (std of residuals). But I was told that the diagonal entries of Ω are σR2 not not σRi. So I did 30 regressions against one variable `timeseriesreturns[,i] ~ dji[,1]` i= 1:30. now I have to use my slopes, intercept and std residuals to make a covariance matrix. How would I make a covariance matrix from this these values?